# Exporting default class complains about name

Tags: javascript

In the MDN docs they use export default class {} and importing it with:

```
import Whatever from './myFile'
```

should work.

This is not working in my case, because I export my class like this:

```
export default class LoginForm extends Component { }
```

And import it like this:

```
import LoginForm from './user/LoginForm';
```

Resulting in the following error:

```
123:30-39 './components/user/LoginForm' does not contain an export named 'LoginForm'.
```

When i add export default LoginForm at the end of my LoginForm file it works, but this feels unneccessary.

Why does it complain about a name anyways if it is a default export?

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Comment: Yes, `import LoginForm from` should work for a default export. `import { LoginForm } from` would not.

Comment: Is this your exact code? Are you sure that you have 
 `export` **`default`** `class …`?

Comment: This is my exact code, but it works now. My error was coming from another file importing it with curly braces (facepalm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When i add export default LoginForm at the end of my LoginForm file it works, but this feels unneccessary.

It might seem unneccessary, but this is a convention that you will often see. 
I guess you are creating a React Component here, keep in mind, that you often have HoC (higher order components) that need to wrap your component export.

Here is an example:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginForm);
```

Therefore it makes sense, to put exports at the end of your file.

Note: I could not reproduce your error, when I exported a component like this:

`export default class App extends Component { ... }`

This worked for me.

Comment: In the comments above you can see it was my fault that i didn't see which file was producing the error. But why makes it sense to put it at the end of the file? What is the difference between putting it right before your class definition or at the end of the file?

Comment: Gald you could fix your issue. It is just a styling convention, to put your default exports at the end of a file.